# calculating the width of a list of loaded images using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a slide show using **jQuery**, the images are loaded using **AJAX** and are put into the list using append. After all images are loaded I want to get the list width.

I'm using this code below, but the problem is that `logos_counter` which is supposed to contain all images width is always equal to 0.

```
var logos_counter = 0;
var img = new Image();
$.each(data.images, function (index, photo) {
   url = 'img/logos/' + photo;
   $('.logos ul').append($('<li>').append($('<img/>').attr('src',url).addClass('slide')));
   img.src = url;
   logos_counter = logos_counter + img.width;
});
$('.logos ul').css({width: logos_counter + 'px'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$.each(data.images, function (index, photo) {
   url = 'img/logos/' + photo;
   $('.logos ul').append($('<li>').append($('<img/>').attr('src',url).addClass('slide')));
   img.src = url;
   $(img).load(function(){
      logos_counter = logos_counter + $(this).width;
      $('.logos ul').css({width: logos_counter + 'px'});
   });

});
```